# monitor won't turn on after reboot

Tags: display, hdmi

After rebooting my machine, my monitor will often not come back on. It will just say "entering power save mode" or "no signal detected."

This has been with three different monitors (two Dell 2007f's pand one Asus), three different PCs (one of which is brand new), and two different HDMI->DVI cables. I'm pretty sure it's an OS issue at this point, because the thing they all have in common is it's always Ubuntu 22.04.

Sometimes I have to turn it on and off many many times, unplug/replug in cables, turn on/off machines, try all these things in different combinations or with different timings. I haven't been able to figure out a consistent way to circumvent this issue even in a hacky way.

On my new PC I run onboard graphics. Here's some driver information

```
taylor@mean-machine:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for taylor: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1600x1200 resolution=1600,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1600 yres=1200
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:158 memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

some cpu info:

```
taylor@mean-machine:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq
model name  : 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-13600K
```

but like I said, I've gotten this on multiple machines. The two older ones had graphics cards with multiple hdmi outputs, and I was always trying different ports all the time.

A thought I had: another thing all these machines have in common are entries like this on a `cron` file:

```
20 9 * * 1-5 export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/bash /opt/ibc/gatewaystart.sh
```

Perhaps that `export DISPLAY` business is messing something up? I'm out of my depth on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the monitor shows the Linux kernel boot-up sequence, it might be good to verify that by booting with the `nosplash` (and removing any `splash`) kernel option.

Does the monitor turn off before the login screen, or only after you login?  If the login screen is affected, you might consider trying a different display manager (than the default gdm) or greeter (I use slick-greeter with lightdm, though I haven't experienced your problem).

It's unlikely to be that cron job, because it's set to run at 9:20am on weekdays, but you have this problem at boot-up (and cronjobs that are scheduled for a time when the computer is off, do not run at startup).  Maybe have a look for a `@reboot` cronjob (in your account's crontab, root's crontab, `/etc/crontab`, and `/etc/cron.d/*`).

Since you don't have a reliable reproducer, I'd encourage you to do more investigation of the system when it's in this state.  You can enable the sshd server, so that you can login from another computer on the network, and then investigate.  For example, you can find out if an X11 server is running (eg. `ps auxw | grep Xorg`), if so try seeing what the xrandr for it reports (`DISPLAY=:0 xrandr -v`).  See how this output changes as you plug/unplug/replug the monitor(s).  Check the active xrandr output resolution, and maybe try forcing a lower one.  Try forcibly waking the screen (`DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on`).  You can try restarting the display manager (`systemctl restart gdm`).  You can look for error messages in `dmesg` and the system logs.

Comment: Yeah, this is tough because I cannot reproduce anything for the life of me. Anyway, I replaced the monitor and it appears that everything is fixed.